# Python read serial from Arduino and skip the first line read

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have an Arduino connected to a Raspberry Pi and I am getting the data from the Arduino using python and serial. I have 6 sensors connected to the Arduino but when I print the data from the pi the first line is always 2 or 3 of the sensors then after that all 6 sensors print out. How would I skip the first line being read over form serial?

My output looks like this:

```
0 2 3
2 4 6 7 8 54
2 3 5 65 7 7
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

First line is always less than 6 sensors and the values come from an array. So if I were to access `arr[4]` it would be out of bounds.

Here is the python code. I am trying to do this without using a while loop, I will be creating another function that calls `sensorVals()` periodically to update the sensor values. I know I can use a loop, check the array length to be 6 then print.

```
import serial
datetime.datetime.now()
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)
def sensorVals():
    while True:
        read_serial=ser.readline()
        val= read_serial.decode()
        val =val.strip()
        row = [x for x in val.split(' ')]
        if len(row) == 6:
            sensor1 = row[0]
            sensor2 = row[1]
            sensor3 = row[2]
            sensor4 = row[3]
            sensor5 = row[4]
            sensor6 = row[5]
            print (sensor4)
sensorVals()
```

Comment: Just add something like `first = True`, and inside your while, do: `if first:` (then pass), `else:` (then your code). Inside the `if` your need to update the value of `first` in order to enter the else on the next loop iteration.

Comment: I am trying not to use a while loop for this. Instead I will be creating another function that calls sensorVals() to obtain the sensor data. The issue is that the first line read is always less than 6 sensors but after that it will be all 6. So i need to skip the first line read

Comment: Anyway, the idea I gave you about having a variable to avoid the first line processing is valid for this approach as well.

Comment: `while True:`, `junk=ser.readline()`, `read_serial=ser.readline()`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Wouldn't that only obtain every second line though?

Comment: I don't know! I guess it could be moved outside the loop, but that's a way to discard a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way without needing a loop, if you're sure that only one line will even be 4 values long:

```
# These lines moved to a new function so we avoid duplication
def readOneSensorLine():
    read_serial=ser.readline()
    val = read_serial.decode()
    val = val.strip()
    return val.split(' ') # You shouldn't need the list comprehension here

def sensorVals():
    row = readOneSensorLine()
    if len(row) == 4:
        # This row is short, so read again
        row = readOneSensorLine()

    return row #or print it, or whatever else needs to be done
```